# Sweet distribution (optimization)

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization

> You got starting amount of Sweets provided suppose N, you are provided T such that every time you distribute T sweets from N, 1 sweet is added. Determine the number of sweets you can distribute.

For ex. N=5 , T=2

- Step1: 5-2+1   sweets distributed:2 remaining sweets :4
- Step2: 4-2+1   sweets distributed:2 remaining sweets :3
- Step3: 3-2+1   sweets distributed:2 remaining sweets :2
- Step4: 2-2+1   sweets distributed:2 remaining sweets :1
- Step5: 1       sweets distributed:1 remaining sweets :0

  Code returns: Total sweet:9

**My code is below:**

```
    public static int countSweets(int n, int t) {
       //recursive code is commented
       /*if(n<t)
         return n;
        return t+countCandies(n-t+1,t);*/

     //simple while loop snippet
       int count=0;
       while(n>=t)
       {
         count=count+t;
         n=n-t+1;
       }
       return count+n;
    }
```

I tried both the methods simple and recursive. Error shown are

1. simple:Time Limit Exceeded
2. recursive:Stack overflow (for higher difference between n and t)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some arithmetics:
There are

```
S =  (N - 1) div (T - 1)   // div is integer division 7 div 3 = 2
```

steps in regular output (giving rest>0).
Every step subtracts (T-1) sweets - denominator. Subtraction goes until 1, not 0 (because you cannot have -1 sweets before addition) - that is why (N-1) nominator.

**Edit:**

So full number of sweets is starting value plus number of added ones (equal to the number of regular steps):

```
F = N + S =
    N + (N - 1) div (T - 1) = 
    (N * (T - 1) + N - 1) / (T - 1) = 
    //very simple formula 

    (N * T - 1) div (T - 1)
```

Check for `(N,T) = (5,2); (7,3); (8,3); (17,4)` gives `9;10;11;22`

Comment: Can you explain s=(N-1) div(T-1)? All steps are perfect and it gives correct answer but how did you come up with s=(N-1)div(T-1)?

Comment: Every step subtracts `(T-1)` sweets - denominator. Subtraction goes until `1`, not `0` (because you cannot have `-1` sweets before addition)- that is why `(N-1)` nominator

Comment: I simplified logic.

Answer (score 1):

Use division by T instead of subtracting T. For N=5, T=2:

1. 5/2 = 2 distributions=2 bonus items & 1 item left over
2. 3/2 = 1 distribution=1 bonus item & 1 item left over
3. 2/2 = 1 distribution=1 bonus item & 0 item left over
4. 1/2 = 0 - partial distribution, 0 bonus items

final count= N+ bonus items = 5+2+1+1+0 = 9

In this example it is only 1 step faster, but for large N it will be more significant.